# Understanding Fourier Transforms in abstract math terms

Tags: fourier-transform, python, algorithms, fourier-series, numerical-algorithms

I am having a hard time implementing a method that computes Fourier transform coefficients for the complex form using the trapezoid rule.

I have floated questions in the math and stackoverflow networks, without getting any kind of answers that I can understand and implement.

Essentially, I am having the following issues:

1. My DFT estimate of any given function seems to be at least off by half. I can correct this by multiplying each DFT coefficient by
   2, but that's probably a terrible thing to do in lieu of finding the
   actual bug.
2. No matter how many coefficients I calculate, the DFT does not converge very well to the exact function (unless I choose to estimate a periodic function).
3. when I add more and more coefficients, things begin to look
   wrong after a certain point.

**EDIT:** Added two plots to illustrate issue #3.

With about 100 terms:
[image]

With 200 terms:
[image]

Unfortunately, you will have to keep the language of your help tailored towards someone who has only done abstract math. Here is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def coefficients(fn, dx, L):
    """
    Calculate the complex form fourier series coefficients for the first M
    waves.

    :param fn: function to sample
    :param dx: sampling frequency
    :param L: We are solving on the interval [-L, L]
    :return: an array containing M Fourier coefficients c_m
    """

    N = 2*L / dx

    # m is the number of DFT coefficients to calculate. N/2 coefficients are sufficient
    # Proof:
    # Minimum sampling given a oscillating function is lambda/2, where lambda is the
    # period of oscillation of the function we sample. In other words dx = lambda/2
    # for a minimally resolved  estimate. So with fixed dx, the smallest wavelength
    # we can hope to resolve is lambda_min = 2*dx. Also note that the wavelength of
    # sin(n*pi*x / L) is given by 2L/n. So then our minimum wavelength is given by
    # lambda_min = 2L/n_min = 2*dx. Rearranging, we see that the smallest wave number
    # n is n_min = 2L/lambda_min = 2L/(2*dx) = L/dx = L/(2L/N) = N/2.

    m = int(N/2 + 1)

    coeffs = np.zeros(m, dtype=np.complex_)
    xk = np.arange(-L, L + dx, dx)

    # Calculate the coefficients for each wave
    for mi in range(m):
        coeffs[mi] = 2/N * sum(fn(xk)*np.exp(-1j * mi * np.pi * xk / L))

    return coeffs


def fourier_graph(range, L, c_coef, function=None, plot=True, err_plot=False):
    """
    Given a range to plot and an array of complex fourier series coefficients,
    this function plots the representation.


    :param range: the x-axis values to plot
    :param c_coef: the complex fourier coefficients, calculated by coefficients()
    :param plot: Default True. Plot the fourier representation
    :param function: For calculating relative error, provide function definition
    :param err_plot: relative error plotted. requires a function to compare solution to
    :return: the fourier series values for the given range
    """
    # Number of coefficients to sum over
    w = len(c_coef)

    # Initialize solution array
    s = np.zeros(len(range))
    for i, ix in enumerate(range):
        for iw in np.arange(w):
            s[i] += c_coef[iw] * np.exp(1j * iw * np.pi * ix / L)

    # If a plot is desired:
    if plot:
        plt.suptitle("Fourier Series Plot")
        plt.xlabel(r"$t$")
        plt.ylabel(r"$f(x)$")
        plt.plot(range, s, label="Fourier Series")

        if err_plot:
            plt.plot(range, function(range), label="Actual Solution")
            plt.legend()

        plt.show()

    # If error plot is desired:
    if err_plot:
        err = abs(function(range) - s) / function(range)
        plt.suptitle("Plot of Relative Error")
        plt.xlabel("Steps")
        plt.ylabel("Relative Error")
        plt.plot(range, err)
        plt.show()

    return s


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Assuming the interval [-l, l] apply discrete fourier transform:

    # number of waves to sum
    wvs = 30

    # step size for calculating c_m coefficients (trap rule)
    deltax = .025 * np.pi

    # length of interval for Fourier Series is 2*l
    l = 2 * np.pi

    c_m = coefficients(np.exp, deltax, l)

    # The x range we would like to interpolate function values
    x = np.arange(-l, l, .01)
    sol = fourier_graph(x, l, c_m, np.exp, err_plot=True)
```

Comment: i just don't wanna look at your code.  and i don't know Python anyway.  could you use $\LaTeX$ to express your mathematical problem in traditional mathematical notation?  usually, factor of two off is due to the double-sided Fourier transform (with both positive and negative frequency) being related to a single-sided with real sinusoids having only positive frequencies.  because: $$ \cos(\omega t) = \tfrac12 (e^{i \omega t} + e^{-i \omega t}) $$ sometimes a factor of 2 sneaks in there.

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean with "the DFT doesn't converge very well to the exact function": Which function? I presume you mean a function on $\mathbb R$, so what kind of measure are you applying to define convergence "quality" (I'm not familiar with "well-converging" as a term, but my analysis education lies a while in the past, so maybe that's a well-defined math term) for a finite sequence of complex numbers and a function on the reals? What is the "certain point" after which things look wrong?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Sure! Well basically the relative error remains high even as more and more terms are added to the finite sequence. I was under the impression that for any smooth function, the Fourier Series should converge to to the exact function as the number of terms approaches infinity. This might have been a misconception on my part. Someone mentioned to me yesterday that functions that are not "square-integrable" will not necessarily converge. I haven't looked up what that means yet.

Comment: @MarcusMüller and to answer your second question, given that my step size for calculating the coefficients is $0.025 \pi$, my plot starts to look wack when I exceed about 100 terms. By the time I get to 200, terms it's totally crazy. I'll post the plots in the question.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Sure thing, here is a link to the question I posted on the math network, although I believe at this point the question about math has been answered and now my question is one of implementation: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3420961/solving-for-coefficients-of-complex-fourier-series?noredirect=1#comment7056363_3420961

Comment: @rocksNwaves "remains high": What does that imply?

Comment: @rocksNwaves and looking at your graphs: there's an overlayed oscillation. What's the frequency of that?

Comment: @MarcusMüller When you say frequency, does that mean how often I sample the function $e^x$ for calculating my coefficients? If so it was $\Delta x = 0.025 \pi$. Sorry, I'm not used to putting physical labels on math constructs yet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big thanks to @user753642 for spotting my mistakes over on the stackoverflow network:

I was computing the $c_n$ coefficients from $n=0 \dots m$, where m is the number of wave functions in the sum. But by definitions the coefficients look like:

$$c_m = \frac{1}{2L}\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty}c_n\delta_{n,m}\int_{-L}^Ldx = \frac{1}{2L}\int_{-L}^L f(x) \exp(\frac{-im\pi x}{L})$$

And the reconstructed function looks like:

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}c_n \exp(\frac{in \pi x}{L})
$$

So when I was reconstructing my function with the Fourier Series with $c_n$ with $n=0…m$, I should have been going from $n=−m/2…m/2$.

This fixed everything, and allowed me to drop the weird $N/2$ factor that I was using. This was achieved by changing the above code int two places. First when calculating the coefficients:

```
# Calculate the coefficients for each wave
for mi in range(m):
    n = mi - m/2
    coeffs[mi] = 1/N * sum(fn(xk) * np.exp(-1j * n * np.pi * xk / L))

return coeffs
```

And then again when reconstructing the function:

```
for i, ix in enumerate(range):
    for iw in np.arange(w):
        n = iw - w/2
        s[i] += c_coef[iw] * np.exp(1j * n * np.pi * ix / L)
```

I have a lot to learn about Fourier Series/Transforms. Thanks for all the helpful comments, everyone.

Comment: You can accept your own answer if you like.

Comment: Apparently I have to weight 24 hours.